# linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic to be reinstalled

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

Starting Synaptic fails w/ : 
Das Paket linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic muss neu installiert werden, es kann jedoch kein Archiv dafür gefunden werden.
on ubuntu 16.04:

I downloaded the .deb package and put it @ /var/cache/apt/archives/

- `apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic`
- `sudo apt-get -f install  ./linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb`
- `apt-get install --reinstall --no-download --fix-missing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic`

and several other stuff, but I didn't manage to reinstall the downloaded package.

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb
```

leads to :

```
(Lese Datenbank ... 581817 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit 
installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-
generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) über 
(4.4.0-83.106) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-
generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) über ( 
4.4.0-83.106) ...
Mehr als eine Kopie des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic 
wurde in diesem Durchlauf
entpackt! Es wird nur einmal konfiguriert.
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-image-
extra-4.4.0-83-generic:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic hängt ab von linux-image-4.4.0-83-
generic; aber:
Paket linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic ist nicht installiert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-
generic (--install):
Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic`
```

I'm trapped in an endless loop ! 
Could please someone help me?

Comment: The error says: `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic` depends on `linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic`, but that is not installed. So first try to install `linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic`.

Comment: You did not inform about the ubuntu version you are running. `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic`is provided in trusty, trusty-updates, xenial and xenial-updates - see `whohas linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic`.